# iPhone app store ID is not working when we enter in Facebook settings?

Tags: ios, facebook, app-store-connect

I am setting up a `facebook` Login. It requires iPhone app store ID. In my iTunesConnect I have setup the app and it has given me the AppID, a numeric number. The app is  in the market(live) . I put that number in my Facebook app setup, but it gives me an error, saying we were unable to fetch app from app store. Where am I going wrong?
Please Help Me .
Thanks in Advance.

Note : The App is on live But Accidentally Facebook Developer App Account is Delete.

Comment: can u provide the image of Particular..

Comment: @iOSDeveloper Thanks . there is Any Short cut to retrieve the Facebook Developer App Account Which was Accidentally Delete.

Comment: did u delete the completed Account  ?

Comment: No. only the app details are deleted..

Comment: Can you post your Facebook App ID and the iTunes App ID that you have used?